# compile postgresql from source

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, compilation

I need to make changes to the mdwrite function in the /src/backend/storage/smgr/md.c file (part of code, because i can't pin screenshot)

```
seekpos = (off_t) BLCKSZ * (blocknum % ((BlockNumber) RELSEG_SIZE));

    Assert(seekpos < (off_t) BLCKSZ * RELSEG_SIZE);

    **buffer[0] = 'A';**

    nbytes = FileWrite(v->mdfd_vfd, **buffer**, BLCKSZ, seekpos, WAIT_EVENT_DATA_FILE_WRITE);

    **buffer[0] = 'B';**

    TRACE_POSTGRESQL_SMGR_MD_WRITE_DONE(forknum, blocknum,
                                        reln->smgr_rnode.node.spcNode,
                                        reln->smgr_rnode.node.dbNode,
                                        reln->smgr_rnode.node.relNode,
                                        reln->smgr_rnode.backend,
                                        nbytes,
                                        BLCKSZ);
```

compilation and installation was successful, but when I configure:

```
 /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

It give me `writing block 0 of relation global/1136` on ubuntu console. How should I work with source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was the point of the change?  It seems to be designed to cause havoc, which is what it did.

The full message should be something like this:

```
LOG:  request to flush past end of generated WAL; request 41/28, currpos 0/1523128
CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation global/1213
FATAL:  xlog flush request 41/28 is not satisfied --- flushed only to 0/1523128
CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation global/1213
```

So you corrupted the LSN in the page header of the buffer to be written, which then caused a request of a WAL flush which is impossible to perform.